# C# MVC RedirectToAction not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

So I want to create a new view in my MVC application that allows a user to enter parameters for searching. I want to pass these parameters to another View/Controller and I want the controller to call an action called "Search" to handle these parameters and return the correct data. However, when I try to "Redirect" it is giving me a problem. It says the resource cannot be found,

```
The view 'Search' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.
The following locations were searched:

~/Views/Question/Search.aspx
```

This is the code.

```
[HttpPost]
           public ActionResult HandleForm()
           {
               SearchQuery search = new SearchQuery();
               if(Request["QuestionID"].Trim()!="")
                search.QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(Request["QuestionID"].Trim());           



return RedirectToAction("Search", "Question");                 
}
```

However, if I change "Search" to "Index" it loads the page I desire because it opens the view within that page. It does not call the search action. Why is this method returning the View when every example I've read states that the name of the Action needs to be passed?

For those who are wondering this is my global.asax routing info

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Last but not least, I have yet to look into how to pass these parameters, but I hope it won't be too much extra work once I can figure out why this is not working as desired.

Comment: A suggestion not related to your question is to checkout AttributeRouting. Saved me from a brain tumor when it comes to routes.

Comment: Can you also include the signature of your Search method that exists in your QuestionController?

Comment: Have you double checked if the file is actually there: `~/Views/Question/Search.aspx` ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Views/Questions` directory and make sure there is a file called `Search.cshtml`.  If it does exist also then make sure that this view has a corresponding action method, something like:

```
public class QuestionController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Search()
     {
     }
}
```

Comment: Well I decided in the end that it would be better instead of trying to redirect to another page ...to just combine the pages. But I've run into even more problems...Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in same controller then write:

```
return RedirectToAction("Search");
```

or if your search action is in other controller then write:

```
return RedirectToAction("Search","your Controller Name Here");
```